# Can I create a NuGet package that references a different source?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have a project I need to publish as a NuGet package.

This project references other NuGet packages, that are available on a MyGet feed.

Is there any way to include a referent to the MyGet feed in my NuGet package, so that these  references will resolve correctly, without having to manually add the MyGet to the package sources in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot define a package source inside the NuGet package.

The only thing you can do is put the package source in a NuGet.Config file and include that with your project. So if you are sharing your source code then NuGet would include that package source when restoring the packages. Or you can just add that to the standard NuGet.Config file using Visual Studio.